# how to create a sha1 hash in python

Tags: python, smartcard, apdu, pyscard

My objective is to perform "Hashsigning" using smart card in  python. there are hashlib's used but there is no specific SHA1 or SHA256 functions in python. 
My Work:

```
hash_object = hashlib.sha1(b'HelWorld')
pbHash = hash_object.hexdigest()
```

but the length of the hash object I get is 28 rather i should get 14 or 20 so that i can switch on condition as

```
 switch ( dwHashLen )
{
case 0x14: // SHA1 hash
             call scard transmit
case 0x20: // SHA256 hash
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by length of hash object? And where do you get 28? SHA1 is 40 chars long.

Comment: and what do you mean `switch` and `case` that is surely not python...

Comment: the sha1 digest itself is 20 bytes - 40 characters hex encoded.  maybe that's what  is meant here. sha256 is 32 bytes (64 characters in hex).  not sure what should be 14 - even md5 is 16 bytes.

Comment: Note that those are hex values that 0x14 is 20 and 0x20 is 32 so you are expecting binary hashes not hex encoded ones. Use `.digest()` not `.hexdigest()` to get the binary hash not the hex encoded one.

Comment: @domoarrigato switch case is in my c code. i am porting to python.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You're actually getting 40, which in hex is `0x28`. Decode the hash in hexadecimal to ASCII as follows

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hash_object = hashlib.sha1(b'HelWorld')
>>> pbHash = hash_object.hexdigest()
>>> length = len(pbHash.decode("hex"))
>>> print length
20
```

Or simply use `digest` instead of `hexdigest` as [Dan D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388787/dan-d) suggested.